# Differentiating: 肚 and 胃 in English?

Tags: translation

In Chinese 肚 and 胃 are two quite seperate things.

In English, though, it's mostly just: *stomach*.

Is there a good way to differantiate between the two in English?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

肚 is belly, 胃 is stomach. So:

> 啤酒肚: Beer belly.
>
> 肚子疼: Pain in the belly, could be the stomach, but may well be the appendage.
>
> 大肚婆: Slang for pregnant woman.
>
> 小肚子: The underbelly. Formal: 下腹 or 小腹.
>
> 肚脐: Belly button.
>
> 肚量大: Big-hearted. (Funny, but we also say 心胸宽广.)

When you read it as `dǔ`, it means the stomach of an animal: `猪肚`, `牛肚`, etc. Usually edible by Chinese standards. Sometimes you hear `肠子肚子` which means "stomach and intestines". A human stomach is NOT called 人肚.

---

Update，肚子疼 vs 胃疼：

> 病人：医生，我肚子疼。
>
> 医生：你肚子哪里疼？
>
> 病人：这里。（Points at the left）
>
> 医生：那应该是胃疼咯。

So 肚子疼 is the pain in the belly area, maybe it's the stomach, maybe not. 胃疼 is more specific, it is the stomach, no doubt about that. Also:

> 女雇员：老板，我肚子疼，今天请个假。
>
> 男老板：那你去医院看看吧。
>
> 女雇员：不用的，休息休息就好。

In this case 肚子疼 means "period pain", and the boss should say things like "好好喝水，多多休息" instead of advising her to go to the hospital.

Comment: How about 肚子疼 vs. 胃痛, we don't really say *belly pain* in English...

Comment: @user3306356 check my update.

Comment: Can we get some English words for the differences in 肚 and 胃 - or are we to simply say stomach for both?!

Comment: @user3306356 肚: belly. 胃: stomach. You can say 肚子疼 if you've got a stomachache, but you can also say 肚子疼 for other inconvenient feelings in your belly. 胃疼 is just the stomachache.

Comment: Bellyache vs Stomachache. I like it. btw: it's not belly pain it would be bellyache - that could totally work. good job.

Answer (score 2):

I did not realize that this is a question about **English**. I should have deleted this answer, but I hope the explanation will help someone anyway.

---

肚 and 胃 belong to **different registers**.

We **almost always** use 肚(子) to refer to abdomen, belly, stomach, etc. It is also used in **idiomatic expressions**. It is also used to refer to the middle part of something, especially when something looks swollen.

胃 is occasionally associated with appetites, but it is mostly used in **scientific** contexts, which unambiguously refers to the stomach organ. Names of diseases, though often heard everyday, never contain 肚. They tend to be more specific to refer to different parts as 胃 (stomach), 腹 (abdomen), 肠 (intestine), etc.

Answer (score 2):

Tummy is similar to belly, and tummy ache is more commonly used than belly ache.

Comment: Tummy is baby speak, in Chinese we have 肚肚 :)

Comment: Note that "tummy" is derived from children's attempt to pronounce "stomach": http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=tummy

Answer (score 1):

肚 is one part of location of your body.

Located under diaphragm and above thigh.

It can also describe lots of thing located there.

for example:

the skin on the 肚　：　肚皮

the hair on the 肚　：　肚毛

following is a picture of body of one person.

Ｏ

／　＼

［＿＿］　＜＝＝＝usually located here.

｜　｜

胃 is just a organ. I think stomach is talking about 胃.

You can say 胃 is in 肚.

Comment: doesn't really answer my question as you I'm looking for names of 肚 vs. 胃 in English aswell...

Comment: If you want a specific English word, I would use belly or abdomen for 肚; stomach for 胃.

Comment: Abdomen, good thinking. I like that. +1

Comment: abdomen sounds formal enough, the counterpart in Chinese i think should be 腹.